# Setting multiple pins on an MKMapView, and have the Callout View show the correct information?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotation

I have an array of objects, which have the information for each pin on my map. I am able to add those with their respective coordinates onto the map using `[mapView addAnnotions:array];`. But when it comes to selecting a pin, and then showing the Callout view for that specific pin(using the right pin location and the right information from my array), I get lost. I also do not entirely know how Callout views work for multiple pins. I've tried looking at Apple Sample Code, but it has not helped very much, and Googling the problem does not help either.

Simple version: How are you supposed to have many pins on a map, and differentiate them when they get selected and when getting called for a callout view?

Edit: For example, how the Maps app on the iPhone works with showing the several locations of businesses, and when you tap them the correct Name and link to said business appears.

Comment: When you create a pin (an annotation), you tell it what the title is and the subtitle text. Then you add all the pins to the map. Then when you tap on the pin, they will show the information for whatever you tell it to display when you create the pin. I usually use a for loop to add all my pins to a map.

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {

static NSString *identifier = @"MyLocation";   
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MNMyLocation class]]) {

    MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *) [atmLocatorMap dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (annotationView == nil) {
        annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    } else {
        annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    }

    annotationView.enabled = YES;
    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
    //annotationView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrest.png"];

    return annotationView;
}

return nil;
```

}

Comment: Could you explain how to incorporate an array with my information into that though?